# How do I apply the definition of derivative to $\sin \left(\frac {1}{x}\right) $?

Tags: real-analysis

Let's say that I have the function
 $\\f (x) =
\begin {cases}
\sin \left(\frac {1}{x}\right), & \text {if $x \ne 0$}\\
0, & \text {if $x=0$}
\end {cases} $

Where $f:\mathbb {R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $

How would I apply the definition of derivative to the case when $x \ne 0$?
Likewise, how would I apply the definition of derivative to the case where $x=0$?
I've looked through some trig identities online so far, but I'm not sure how to use them for this problem.

Comment: I can't think of anything smarter than reproducing the proof of $f(g(x))'=f'(g(x))g'(x)$, where $f(x) = \sin x$ and $g(x) = 1/x$.

Comment: Are you sure you need to apply the definition when $x\neq 0$ instead of just using the chain rule? That looks pretty hard.

Comment: @saulspatz: I don't really have to apply the definition, but I kind of just wanted to see how it would be done.

Comment: Then Ennar's idea seems reasonable.  I certainly don't have a better one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want
$$
\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\sin\dfrac{1}{x}-\sin\dfrac{1}{a}}{x-a}
$$
Apply the sum-to-product formula:
$$
\sin\dfrac{1}{x}-\sin\dfrac{1}{a}=2\cos\frac{a+x}{2ax}\sin\frac{a-x}{2ax}
$$
The part leading to indetermination is the sine, so you want
$$
\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\sin\dfrac{a-x}{2ax}}{x-a}=
\lim_{x\to a}-\frac{1}{2ax}\frac{\sin\dfrac{x-a}{2ax}}{\dfrac{x-a}{2ax}}=-\frac{1}{2a^2}
$$
Also
$$
\lim_{x\to a}\cos\frac{a+x}{2ax}=\cos\frac{1}{a}
$$
so the derivative is
$$
2\frac{-1}{2a^2}\cos\frac{1}{a}=-\frac{1}{a^2}\cos\frac{1}{a}
$$

The chain rule is *much* easier. Now try with
$$
f(x)=\sin\frac{3e^x-2\cos x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}
$$
and enjoy. `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{d(\sin [f(x)])}{dx}=f'(x)\cos[f(x)]$$